# How can I preg_replace both <br /> and ><h2>&nbsp;</h2> in text?

Tags: regex, ckeditor, preg-replace

I am trying to make my own CRM for a small blog site. I use Laravel and CKEditor for the articles. The problem is that CKeditor adds many `<br />` and `<h2>&nbsp;</h2>` inside articles.

I have used the below code to clear the unnecessary `<br />`s.

```
{{  preg_replace('/(<br[\s]?[\/]?>[\s]*){2,}/', '',$post->content())  }}
```

How can I add empty h2 rule inside preg_replace string? and second question is why CKeditor is adding these line breaks? Can someone help me?

Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with `OR` statement:

```
{{  preg_replace('/(<br[\s]?[\/]?>[\s]*){2,}|<h2>(?:&nbsp;)*<\/h2>/i', '',$post->content())  }}
```

That's a known issue about those `br` tags. You can avoid them by modifying Editor configs. But I don't know about generating `h2` tags.

Comment: thank you.this works like a charm. br's I knew it but those additional h2's and p' with &nbsp; is quite new for me.